# FoundrySansExpertMedium font issue in Firefox browser when the text start with capital F

Tags: html, firefox, fonts

I am using the font "FoundrySansExpertMedium" and words that start with "FI" display a space instead, using Firefox.

An example of this can be found on http://support.eworks.ws/eworks/staging/2015/font%20issue/index/index.html, where the word "FIORINO" renders as " ORINO" instead (note the space).

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please show code, [and proof](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), of what you're seeing, so people don't have to play a guessing game when they take time out of their day to help you figure this out. And adding a URL that people can visit to see the problem in question will be very useful, too.

Comment: Hi Thanks, just added the URL

Comment: It looks like you generated a subset from the "real" Foundry Sans Expert font, which still contains ligature substitution rules for `f + i = ﬁ` and `f + l => ﬂ`, but does not actually contain outlines for either `ﬁ` or `ﬂ` in their true spot anymore: http://imgur.com/ljJZyd2. You'll also there are no capital letters in this font... so the simplest solution would be to use the real font that [Monotype has made available](http://www.foundrytypes.co.uk/the-foundry-typefaces/sans/params/foundry-sans).

Comment: Hi, The issue is fixed, when we added the code " -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;" in the CSS, this is the updated link: http://support.eworks.ws/eworks/staging/2015/font%20issue/index/index1.html

Comment: that's very odd... modern Firefox supports default ligatures out of the box, so either this font doesn't have them marked as "default", or that's a pretty old version of Firefox. For Chrome, adding explicit CSS is always necessary, so it's a good thing you found it - to be sure every browsers picks it up, http://help.typekit.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1789736-syntax-for-opentype-features-in-css has some good "catchall" rules.